# Connectivity method does not get invoked in xamarin forms / c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application that should fire a method to execute once it detects Internet Connectivity. I have used

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged
```

to monitor internet connectivity changes which works well.

I then invoke the method in the constructor of the page along with other methods that need to be executed on page load. But when I changed the status of the internet connection, the method `SendUntransferedData();` does not get executed. Hence all my untransferred data are not transferred. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue or provide me an alternative way of doing this?

The following code in MainPage.cs are:

```
public MainPage() {
  DoSomething();
  SearchData();
  SendUntransferedData();
 }
```

The code is implemented in the cs also.

```
private void SendUntransferedData()
{
     CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged +=  (sender, args) =>
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

         da.SendUntransferredData();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:**

First, you need to add these two packages

```
Xam.Plugin.Connectivity
plugin.wifiinfo
```

in all platforms

**Step2:**

Create one class in PCL.

**NetworkCheck.cs**

```
public static bool IsNetworkConnected ()
{
  bool retVal = false;

  try 
  {
    retVal = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
    return retVal;
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (ex.Message);
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

**Step3:**

In your pages use the code below

```
if (CheckNetworkAccess.IsNetworkConnected ())
{
    Navigation.PushAsync (new HomePage ());
} 
else
{
    await DisplayAlert ("Your app name", "Please check your network connection", "OK");
}
```

Comment: No. I want a sort of background service that monitors the Internet Connectivity in the app. As soon as connection is restored, it automatically gets triggered to execute my method `da.SendUntransferredData();`

Answer (score 0):

The alternative I use is the following. In my **App.xaml.cs** file I add the code to hook up the ConnectivityChanged. That way I have one spot in my app where this is handled and since **App.xaml.cs** is always around for the lifetime of my app it's an ideal spot to put this.

If hooks up to the events from CrossConnectivity and then uses the Xamarin Forms [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to broadcast a message to all the subscribers.

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    // Handle when your app starts
    OnResume();
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
    Settings.IsConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectivityChanged;
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged -= ConnectivityChanged;
}

protected async void ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Save current state and then set it
    var connected = Settings.IsConnected;
    Settings.IsConnected = e.IsConnected;

    // If connectivity changes we inform our listeners of that.
    if (connected != e.IsConnected)
        MessagingService.Current.SendMessage(MessageKeys.ConnectivityChanged);

    // If we disconnected, show a message for the user that we did.
    if (connected && !e.IsConnected)
    {
        // We went offline, should alert the user and also update ui (done via settings)
        var task = UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("You are offline.", "Connection lost", "OK");
        if (task != null)
            await task;
    }
}
```

I then create a property in a base viewmodel that all my other viewmodels inherit from. This can be bound to interface controls whenever necessary.

```
public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
```

In my viewmodel I then subscribe to the event that is being thrown in **App.xaml.cs**.

```
MessagingService.Current.Subscribe(MessageKeys.ConnectivityChanged, (c) =>
{
     IsConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;

     // Additional things you want to do such as
     // DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
     // da.SendUntransferredData();
});
```

You could probably abstract this a bit further depending on the MVVM framework you use (if you use one) but I will not go into that since it's unrelated to the original question. This solution uses additional NuGet packages namely:

- [FormsToolkit](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.forms-toolkit/wiki/Services#messagingservice) which has a simplified version of the `MessagingCenter`
- [Settings](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) plugin to store the IsConnected state.

Comment: I have added the following `            CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.IsConnected)
                {
                    DatabaseAccess dba = new DatabaseAccess();
                    dba.SendUntransferredData();
                }
            };`

But the method `SendUntransferredData` does not get executed.

Comment: Where did you add that piece of code? And also, did you add the CrossConnectivity package to all your projects (PCL, Droid, iOS)?

Comment: Yes I have added the package in all projects. I used this code to monitors the internet connectivity. It fires when the app is connected. This part works fine. But the method `dba.SendUntransferredData()` does not executed.

Comment: Do you have a complete sample you could put on Github somewhere we could look at? It's very hard to diagnose an issue when all you have to go on is that one piece of code.

Comment: Ok. Wait a min.. I document the issue on pastebin with all the codes.

Comment: Here is an overview of the type of logic I want to achieve - https://pastebin.com/ay72jSm6 

Can you help me resolving the issue please.

Comment: Even in your sample the ConnectivityChanged gets called without a problem on my end. http://imgur.com/a/7nQIJ What are you testing this on? You have to test this on a physical device because on a simulator this will not work.

Comment: Yes the ConnectivityChanged get called here too.. I am testing it on a physical device. But the `dba.SendUntransferredData()` method does not get executed. :(

Comment: The method definitely gets executed in this scenario. Perhaps somewhere in there something goes wrong and due to the fact that you're using async methods you're not seeing the error pop up. I can't help you any further with this because it probably goes wrong somewhere in your own specific code.